# PHP wp_get_referer not setting a value (sometimes)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on something more complex than this, but I've narrowed down the problem to a very simple bit of PHP code that works on one website but not on others.  I want to use PHP to wp_get_referer, then at the very least, print it out on the screen.  (I've gotten many steps further and actually accomplished the larger goal that I want, but only on one site.)  This works fine on my own site that I'm just using as a testing ground, but I can't seem to get it to work on any of the real, live sites that I actually want to implement it on.  The wp_get_referrer just seems to have no value everywhere else, even when I'm linking directly there from a test page.  It should be printing out that URL the same way it does on my test site, but it's not.

Here's the extra-basic code I've narrowed it down to (linked from http://pixelmixology.com/test.htm, this prints the referring URL at the top):

```html
    <?php
         $refersource = wp_get_referer();
         echo $refersource;
    ?>
```

Another site using the same WP theme, with that same code input into the same spot in the header.php file, does not work.  If I follow the link at http://pixelmixology.com/test2.htm, it isn't printing out the referrer on that site.

Any ideas on what might cause this kind of inconsistency?  I'm kind of a newbie to PHP so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: the referer is browser, and may not be sent (or be fake), it can NEVER be relied on

Comment: The referer is the site I linked from on my own domain, in the first example (and you can see it show up in the test). I don't quite understand what you're getting at about it being the browser itself(?) in other cases. Why would it not be sent in the exact same browser, using the exact same method?  I understand that some sites may spoof the referring URL (or not send that data) but I'm not doing that here.

Comment: sorry missing word should read: "the referer is browser **set**"

Comment: I do understand that it's set by the browser. I was just hoping for some insight as to why it couldn't be detected sometimes when the referring URL was being sent by the same site, in the same browser, using the same code. I don't have any WP plugins installed on the other sites that I think would block the referrer data; why would other sites have issues detecting my referring URL in such a simple scenario?

Comment: "referring URL was being sent by the same site" no its sent by the browser, the site has nothing to do with it. You still seem to think its an issue with your code, when it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: My point is, the browser should be detecting and printing out the same URL considering that all relevant circumstances (that I know of) are the same.  Pointing out that it's the same site was meant to clarify that it's my own domain and not some other website that might be spoofing the URL or not sending one.  Does that make sense?  I'm asking why this same code would sometimes not cause the same result then using the same browser, the same referring URL, using the same code each time.  I don't know where the problem is (code or otherwise) - that is what I'm asking for some help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem, use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in place of wp_get_referer().  I'm not sure why but it works when the other sometimes doesn't.  Hopefully this saves someone else the same hours of trial, error, and confusion.

Comment: It must be because of this: `If it’s the same as the current request URL, will return false.`. So when the referrer is the same as the current URL, it returns false instead of returning the current URL.

Answer (score 2):

Might be part of the explanation: wp_get_referer() returns "False" if the referrer = active URL.